# Java not recognizing the Windows path

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I have set up Java in Windows environment variable, but when I type `java -version` it is not taking the path specified.

So the user path has
`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

And the value of `JAVA HOME` is
`M:\java\java-se-8u41-ri` // this points to jdk 8

When I type `java -version`, I get

```
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is not JDK. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

EDIT : this is what i'm expecting

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_41-b04)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT 2**
information requested

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
M:\java\java-se-8u41-ri
```

```
where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
M:\java\java-se-8u41-ri\bin\java.exe
```

```
echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\lib;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;M:\java\java-se-8u41-ri\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin;M:\maven\apache-maven-3.8.3\bin;
```

Comment: Your java binary seems to be invoked correctly, version 1.8 means java version 8 , so I don't see any issues here ! Why do you think that "This is not JDK" ?

Comment: no this is what i expect as java version `1.8.0_41`

Comment: The JAVA_HOME does not configure the PATH, unless you explicitly added JAVA_HOME to the PATH, and only when the PATH is initialized. Also there could be a different java earlier on the path.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it has been added to the path and to the environment variable as well and no there are no other java versions expect the one i specified

Comment: Please show the result of `echo %PATH%`, `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `where java`. As an aside, you really shouldn't use an ancient version like 1.8.0_41. The most recent version of Java 8 is 1.8.0_312.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with *all* the information I asked, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: @AkashJain Add this information to your question. I hope you already see the problem. java is found twice in your path.

Comment: @Christian yes but that how was it configured , shouldn't windows take the one i specified on the environment variable?

Comment: Windows searches the PATH in the order listed, so it finds java in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` and doesn't look further.

Comment: @AkashJain Doesn't matter how it was configured. It is not the behavior you desire. Put the JAVA_HOME/bin path in front of your PATH declaration.

Comment: yup , the issue was resolved as mark said it dint look further after the first search and once removed it worked perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a great thanks to [@Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) and [@Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534858/christian).

The issue was there were multiple Java installations (as visible in `where java`).

The `path` variable was pointing to Oracle Java at first and was ignoring the Java that I wanted it to point, once I removed it from the path, it started working fine.